# How to apply the probability models?

Tags: probability

For this question, I'm not sure which formula I am supposed to use to calculate the probability. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Suppose your right knee is sore 15% of the time, and your left knee is sore 10%
of the time. What is the largest possible percentage of time that at least one of your
knees is sore? What is the smallest possible percentage of time that at least one of your
knees is sore?

R means right knee and L means left knee

$P(R) = 0.15$

$P(L) = 0.10$

$P(R\cap L) = 0.15+0.10 = 0.25$

Comment: In your last line, you would want $\cup$, not $\cap$ as adding the two is the union.  The addition is only correct if the events are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a Venn diagram.  The maximum chance that one is sore comes when they are never sore at the same time, which gives $0.10+0.15=0.25$.  The minimum chance that at least one is sore comes when there is maximum overlap.  Here all $0.10$ of the time the left is sore, so is the right.  The chance at least one is sore is then the $0.15$ of the time that the right is sore as the left doesn't add anything to it.

Comment: So the max is 0.25, but wouldn't the min be 0.10 then because it's when at least one is sore?

Comment: No, the right is sore $0.15$ of the time.  The fraction of the time that one of them is sore cannot be less than that, because you add the time that just the left is sore

Comment: I am confused. How do we find the minimum chance that one of the knees is sore? 0.15 is only for the right knee

Comment: It could be that either both knees are sore, which is $0.10$ of the time and accounts for all the time the left is sore, or that just the right is sore.  We have accounted for $0.10$ of the time the right is sore, so there is $0.05$ left.  That $0.05$ of the time only the right is sore.  In the Venn diagram in this case the region that is L but not R is empty.

Comment: So how did we get 0.05? did we do time right knee is sore subtracted by time left knee is sore?

Comment: exactly.........

Comment: And is 0.05 is the intersection right?

Comment: No, the intersection in this case is $0.10$.  That is the time both hurt.

Comment: So what is 0.05?

Comment: It is the time only the right is sore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77380/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-dg123).